# Why Login.asp are used?

Tags: asp.net

I've seen that mostly 90% of loginpages.asp are hacked using the Password : 1'or'1'='1

But still seems that they've not changed it and using the same validation method. I've checked the same method in my project which has login page as .jsp and it returns as incorrect credentials, mine is just a simple one but publishing a website is to be in high standard right? Their authentication is very poor compared to my authentication.

People told that 1'or'1'='1 is a simple SQL command. I dont know how it works because I've not worked on any asp pages. Kindly explain how that password works. Thanks

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an [Sql Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Basically, if the code product SQL query based on string concatenation, the final query may contain a always true condition and allow the attacker to log in without knowing the actual password.

Using ASP.Net, if you write some ADO Sql Query, [**always** use SqlParameter object](http://besttechnologyblog.com/2014/02/24/ado-net-how-to-prevent-sql-injection-attack/). All the escaping will be handled by ADO.Net.

Comment: Thanks. Your Sql Injection wikipedia link explains everything.